# Conversão de data para o oracle

Tags: java, oracle, data

Estou com um problema, eu estou tentando salvar uma data no oracle com o formatado `dd/MM/yyyy`, porém, no banco ele apresenta a data no formato `dd/MM/yy`.

Então, me surgiu a dúvida, se o tipo que eu usei na tabela não é adequado, ou, se a data que eu passo para o banco que esta errada.

bom, no meu DAO (no java), para incluir a data, eu converto ela com os seguintes métodos:

```
    public static java.sql.Date converteParaBanco(Date data) {
            return new java.sql.Date(data.getTime());
    }

   public static Date converteDoBanco(java.sql.Date data) {
            return new Date(data.getTime());
   }
```

aplicando o método no DAO:

`ps.setDate(5, ConverteData.converteParaBanco(pojoCompra.getDataCompra()));`

dando um system.out na linha acima, percebi, que meu método faz a data ficar no formato de `2017-09-22`.

Meu atributo no banco, está do tipo `DATE`.

O que eu poderia fazer para que a data seja salva e também retornada com o formato de `dd/MM/yyyy` ?

Comment: Lembre que uma data não é salva em nunhum formato , internamente é um número e a conversão é feita na saída conforme a opção de ambiente , sessão ou do select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1º somente na sessao do usuário alterar o formato

```
sql> ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD/MM/YYYY';
sql> select sysdate from dual;
SYSDATE

SQL> ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS';
--Sessão alterada.
SQL> select sysdate from dual;
SYSDATE
```

`NLS_DATE_FORMAT = ‘DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS’` esse é o formato da  strings  date  do oracle.

Pode alterar o padrão se estiver usando o `SQLDeveloper`

Segundo o seguintes passos:

- Tools > Preferences.
- Na janela que abrir Seleciona Database > NLS
- No Date Format coloque o formato desejado

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: como eu abro esse arquivo ?

Comment: sim, porém ele me retornou 22/09/17

Comment: Session alterado.

>>Query Run In:Resultado da Consulta 2
Erro a partir da linha : 10 no comando -
 SYSDATE
Relatório de erros -
Comando Desconhecido

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66039/discussion-between-bruno-h-and-alunooracle).